# Django: Serving server files with Apache and mod_xsendfile

Tags: django, apache2

I am having trouble serving my server files for User download. I am using Apache with mod_xsendfile. Firstly, if I try to download the file on the development server the file is of 0 bytes. Secondly, if I try to serve the file using Apache I get the error

SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to ***** denied on the line document.file.path

```
file_name = document.file.name          
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % smart_str(file_name)
response['X-Sendfile'] = document.file.path
return response
```

I have configured mod_xsend with "Xsend On". Appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python code looks oj to me, in your apache config you have to configure mode_xsendfile like in this example:

```
<Files *.*>
XSendFile on
XSendFilePath /absolute/path/to/your/files
</Files>
```

Also make sure, that mod_xsendfile is loaded correctly.

Comment: Thanks Jingo... Previously, I had the setting for XSendFile but instead of path settings I was using XSendFileAllowAbove. So, to move on, I had to removed the mod_xsendfile and move to a totally new solution which is remarkably more easier and faster.